# Question related to Imf Ker f for a linear mapping f.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let F be a mapping from $R^3$ to $R^3$ be defined by $F(x_1,x_2,x_3) =(x_1-x_2, x_2-x_3, x_3-x_1)$

A) What are the conditions in order that (a,b,c)$\in Imf$ ?

B) What are the conditions in order that (a,b,c)$\in Ker f$.

Clearly I got for B) (a,b,c)$\in kerf$ when a=b=c.

I m stuck for A).

I want to find a, b ,C satisfying

$x_1 -x_2 =a$,
$x_2-x_3=b$
$x_3-x_1=c$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix of $F$ is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and Gaussian elimination gives
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets R_2+R_1 \\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+R_2 \\
\end{align}
From this we infer that a basis of the image is formed by the first two columns of $A$ and that a basis of $\ker F$ consist of the vector
$(1,1,1)$. So a vector $(a,b,c)$ belongs to $\ker F$ if and only if $a=b=c$.

For a vector $(a,b,c)$ to belong to $\operatorname{im}F$ we need the linear system represented by the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a \\
-1 & 1 & b \\
0 & -1 & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has a solution. Again an elimination gives
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a \\
-1 & 1 & b \\
0 & -1 & c
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & a+b \\
0 & -1 & c
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\gets R_2+R_1 \\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & a+b \\
0 & 0 & a+b+c
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3+R_2 \\
\end{align}
so $a+b+c=0$.

As you see, you don't need to guess. The two eliminations could have been performed together:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & b \\
0 & -1 & 1 & c
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 & a+b \\
0 & -1 & 1 & c
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets R_2+R_1 \\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 & a \\
0 & 1 & -1 & a+b \\
0 & 0 & 0  & a+b+c
\end{array}\right]
&& R_3\gets R_3+R_2 \\
\end{align}
giving the same information.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What can you say about $a + b + c$ if $(a,b,c) \in {\rm Im \ } f$?

Another hint: you may like to use the fact that the dimension of the image plus the dimension of the kernel equals the dimension of the domain, i.e. three.

Comment: That means the condition for (a,b,c)$\in im f$ if a+b+C=0

Answer (score 1):

Hint. You can firstly find basis of $Ker(f)$. Then complete this basis to be basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And then find image of these completing vectors. They will be a basis of $Im(f)$.